# Two AdMob Adds - integration issue

Tags: android, admob

So I just integrated my AdMob .jar file to my project. When I write some code from the AdMob Documentation to my Project:

```
// Create the adView
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER,
                "MY-ID");

        // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it's been given
        // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        // Add the adView to it
        layout.addView(adView);

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

When I added required permissions to my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Finally I added the actual ad banner to my main_activity.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout" >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="MY-ID"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
        </com.google.ads.AdView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

But there is an issue with that. In my actual layout preview, it only shows up one Ad, but when I launch my app on my device, I'm getting **TWO** Ad Banners. Maybe someone will know what could be wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `activity layout preview` doesn't show or process the `java file`. Like if you change the background in the `class` you won't preview it on the `layout preview`.

```
// Create the adView
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER,
                "MY-ID");

        // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it's been given
        // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        // Add the adView to it
        layout.addView(adView);

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

this code you are adding an `adView` in your `class`, it's done, it's added.

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="MY-ID"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

then here you are adding another `adView` in your `xml`, so the `layout preview` will show it.

So now you have two  `adViews`. one you setup in your `class`, and the other in your `xml`.

---

you can delete either one if you want to show only one, and if you want to show both and showing in your `layout preview`, remove the one in your `java class`, and add another `xml` one.